# Python dictionary to variable assignments based on key value to variable name

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, variable-assignment

Basically, I want to take a

Dictionary like `{ "a":"bar", "b":"blah", "c":"abc", "d":"nada" }`

and use it to set variables (in an Object) which have the same name as a key in the dictionary.

```
class Foo(object)
{
    self.a = ""
    self.b = ""
    self.c = ""
}
```

So in the the end self.a = "bar", self.b = "blah", etc... (and key "d" is ignored)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Translating your `class` statement to Python,

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = self.b = self.c = ''
  def fromdict(self, d):
    for k in d:
      if hasattr(self, k):
        setattr(self, k, d[k])
```

the `fromdict` method seems to have the functionality you request.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo(object):
    a, b, c = "", "", ""

foo = Foo()

_dict = { "a":"bar", "b":"blah", "c":"abc", "d":"nada" }
for k,v in _dict.iteritems():
    if hasattr(foo, k):
        setattr(foo, k, v)
```

Comment: I like this approach slightly better. Might be worth noting though that iteritems() is removed in 3.x in favour of items(). Not sure what version the OP is using.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use argument unpacking:

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self, a='', b='', c='', **kwargs)
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
         self.c = c

d = { "a":"bar", "b":"blah", "c":"abc", "d":"nada" }

f = Foo(**d)
```

Comment: Can you please explain this "argument unpacking"?

Comment: @Tengis: `d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}; f(**d)` is the same as `f(a=1, b=2)`